# Cognos security issue

Tags: cognos

How to restrict query studio to only one group in Cognos. My manager wants me to give the access to query studio only to one group and no other user who is not part of that group should have access to query studio? If i delete the existing capabilities of query studio and add that group to the capabilities,. Will that affect the whole system?  It has authors,directory administrators, Everyone, query users and report administrators in its permissions. What happens if i delete all of them and add just the group that needs access? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you not have a non-production environment to test in?

Answer (score 0):

Cognos security is a union of all of the groups and capabilities a user belongs to.  So if you only want certain users to have the capability to use Query Studio, you need to have a group that is assigned the capability for Query Studio and remove other groups who should not have access.

You will likely end up with some users who belong to more than one LDAP group (for instance, a user may belong to "Department A" which gives them object visibility to reports for their department, and "Query Studio Users" which gives them the capability to use Query Studio).

The way I approach it is to identify each user between two functions: their "capability" i.e. what they can do in Cognos, and their "visibilty" i.e. what they should see.  You should have enough LDAP groups to cover all combinations.